# リストから取り出した3つの整数の合計が0になる組み合わせ

Tags: python, アルゴリズム

EDIT: 最初に投稿した時は、N個の整数の合計の一般解を求める問題だと思っていたのですが、一般解だとNP完全問題になってしまうので、出題者の意図は３つ限定だったのだろうと思います。ですので３つの合計に改題しました。回答を考えてくださった皆さんすみません！

---

ある任意の長さのリストに符号つきの整数が格納されています。値の重複を許します。そこから３つの整数を取り出すとき、合計が0になる組み合わせを求めなさいという問題が解けません。どうぞご教授ください。

**条件**

- itertoolsを使えば下のように簡単に計算できますが、itertoolsは使わないものとします。
- メモリを3回走査するとtime complexity(CPUタイム)はO(N^3)になります。それよりは効率のよい方法で実装したいです。
- space complexity(メモリ効率)は犠牲にしていいです。
- ソートやリストのコピーなど前処理を行っても構いません。

**検算用のコード**

```
import itertools
l=[-3, 2, 1, -2, 0, 5, -1 , -1]
for c  in itertools.combinations(l, 3):
    if sum(c) == 0:
        print c
```

**答え**

```
(-3, 2, 1)
(-3, -2, 5)
(2, -2, 0)
(2, -1, -1)
(1, 0, -1)
(1, 0, -1)
```

**今まで調べたこと**

itertools.combinationのマニュアルには同等のアルゴリズムのソースがありました。このアルゴリズムはO(N)だそうです。

```
def combinations(iterable, r):
    # combinations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BC BD CD
    # combinations(range(4), 3) --> 012 013 023 123
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = range(r)
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != i + n - r:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[i] += 1
        for j in range(i+1, r):
            indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1
        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
```

これだけでも十分速いと思いますが、与えられた問題とデータの性質に合わせてより効率的な方法はないかと模索しています。

条件のところに書いていますが、ヒントはソートしても良いし、リストのコピーを作っても良い、とのことです。また取り出す個数が3でなくて2ならどうか？とも聞かれました。2つなら辞書にd[-1]=1などとして、リストに存在する符号が反対の値の組合せを保存しておけば、O(1)で計算できることになります。しかしこれでは重複する値に対応できないし、3つ以上に拡張できるのか、全く見当もつきません。

**類題**

部分和問題という類題は任意の数の部分和を探すもので、僕に与えられた問題はサブセットということになりそうです。なんとなく、見た目より遥かに難しい問題だということはわかりました。

[部分和問題](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)。NP完全だそうです...。

**さらに調べてわかったこと**

取り出す個数が３の時は"3sum問題"として、ダイナミックプログラミング(DP、動的計画法)のO(N^2)の解が知られている。

[本家StackOverflow N=3の時の回答](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22905617/given-an-array-of-sorted-integers-how-can-i-find-if-there-exists-a-set-of-3-ele)　コードも簡単。
[３和問題](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ほとんど本家からのコピーですが、3つの和限定の解です。

```
l=[-3, 2, 1, -2, 0, 5, -1 , -1]
l.sort()
M = len(l) - 1
for i, e in enumerate(l):
    j = i + 1
    k = M
    while k > j:
        s = l[i] + l[j] + l[k]
        if s == 0:
            print l[i], l[j], l[k]
            k -= 1
        elif s > 0:
            k -= 1
        else:
            j += 1
```

**結果**

```
-3 -2 5
-3 1 2
-2 0 2
-1 -1 2
-1 0 1
-1 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

とりあえず、`itertools.combination`はO(N)ではありません。O(N^3)です。
というのも、`combination(iterable, 3)`は、`iterable`から3個の要素を選ぶすべての場合を返すので、
N個から3個選ぶ方法、N(N-1)(N-2)/6だけ時間がかかります。

長さ`N`の配列`a`に対して、O(N^2)解法は以下の通りです。

1. 連想配列`dict`を用意し、`dict[i]=(a[j]=iとなるjの個数)`となるようにする
2. `dict`のキーを配列`x`にソートして格納する
3. `sum=0`とする
4. `0<=i<j<len(x)`に対して、5.を実行する。
5. `-(x[i]+x[j])`が`dict`のキーとして含まれていれば、`sum+=dict[-(x[i]+x[j])]`とする
6. `sum`が答え

Comment: すいません、これだと重複ができますね。<br/>
少し面倒ですが、`(0,0,0)`の場合、`(0,p,-p)`の場合、`(p,q,-p-q)`の場合、`(-p,-q,p+q)`の場合で<br/>
分けて求める必要があります(`p,q>0`とします)。<br/>
<br/>
`(0,0,0)`は、`dict[0]=k`として`k*(k-1)*(k-2)/6`通りです。<br/>
<br/>
`(0,p,-p)`の場合、`0`の選び方が`k`通りで、`(p,-p)`の部分は以下のようにします。<br/>
    `i=len(x)-1
    sum=0
    while i>=0 && x[i]>0:
        if -x[i] in dict:
            sum += dict[-x[i]]
        i--`
pythonはほとんど触ったことがないので、エラーが出るかもしれません。<br/>
ともかく、この場合は`k*sum`通りです。<br/>
<br/>
`(p,q,-p-q)`の場合は回答で述べた通りですが、`i,j`は`x[i]>0 && x[j]>0`を満たす範囲で<br/>
動かす必要があります。<br/>
<br/>
`(-p,-q,p+q)`の場合も同様です。<br/>